# Waterproof over Fiberglass Deck Material

Tags: deck, exterior

My existing exterior deck is wood structure with a fiberglass mat affixed to its surface. It has a coating that was applied to create a faux tile finish.  It is now leaking after 15 years of service. The deck is used for entertaining and gets foot traffic. Can I apply a clear **Drylok** product over this surface to waterproof and improve appearance?

Comment: maybe,  but if you want it to last another 15 years you should probably use a product intended for wood/fibreglass surfaces.

Comment: Thanks Jasen. That is exactly the issue. I haven't yet identified a product that seems correct. Someone  recommended Drylock but I wasn’t sure it was right answer.  Any product recommendations?  Terry

Comment: fibreglass and resin is used to waterproof some showers. perhapos look at shower membrane products.